# How to ignore some UI elements as seperators or ImageViews for Talkback?

Tags: android, androidx, talkback

I tried [Talkback](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback) accessibility service on my app.

[image]

When I navigate through my app I have:

- some line seperators, where Talkback reacts sensitive and talks something on that seperator which does not make any sense.
- images beneath its explanation text, where talkback reacts sensitive to the images, instead of jumping to the text beneath and read the text here.

1. How can I ignore UI elements like seperators completely?
2. How can I ignore some certain designated images and navigate to their text explanation beneath instead?

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for implementing/testing accessibility in your app!

To disable accessibility behavior, since API 16 you can use the `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` attribute, or programmatically via

```
myView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO)
```

or

```
ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(myView, ViewCompat.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

To ignore some certain designated images and use their text explanation beneath you can set the text explanation as the `contentDescription` on the image.  Talkback will read a views contentDescription.

```
myImageView.setContentDescription (string-value-from-caption)
```

Comment: Since I do not use any layouts anymore and I only have Composables .. what would be the pendant for Jetpack Compose? There is a `Modifier.toggleable`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know Compose.  You might try setting `contentDescription=null`?

Comment: Its still selectable and navigatable with nulling contentDescription

Comment: For Compose `Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { }` should ignore the View